# Is sorting a list or creating a binary search tree and doing an in-order traversal faster?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, binary-search-tree

Of the below, which is a better approach?

1. Sorting a list of elements, or
2. Creating a binary search tree from a list, and then creating another list performing in-order traversal

All I have to do actually is have a list of values and, as per the position of those values, assign a rank to them.

Suppose I have a list:

```
[33735, 0, 1368, 5400, 123, 2317, 43654, 243730]
```

I want to have the values in a sorted fashion and then assign rank.
Which method should I use?

Comment: Which approach performed better in your tests?

Comment: A sorted list in python can be visited with binary search.

Comment: Right now I am using the binary tree inorder traversal method, which is working fine. But I was just wondering that since I am getting a sorted list in the end, then why not just sort the list and use it?

Answer (score 0):

I think that trees are kind of overkill in this case unless you need to update the collection frequently while maintaining the ranks. Otherwise, you can simply loop through the sorted list :

```
l = [33735, 0, 1368, 5400, 123, 2317, 43654, 243730]
for rank, item in enumerate(sorted(l)):
    # do what you need
    print rank, item
```

Comment: This list is created by hitting on the database, every time you visit a certain page.

Comment: If the structure isn't reused at all, building BST makes no sense.

Comment: then you should use the ORDERBY sql close or its equivalent and let the DBMS handle the sorting for you. It will be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Asymptotically speaking, they're the same.

Point #2 itself is actually a sorting algorithm, known as [tree sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_sort), with an `O(n log n)` worst-case running time (assuming we're using a [self-balancing BST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree)).

Any comparison-based sort (presumably #1) also [has a worst-case `O(n log n)` worst-case running time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort#Lower_bound_for_the_average_number_of_comparisons).

Practically speaking, a library sort function (which would probably use something like [quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort), [merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) or [timsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) to name 3) would likely be faster (there's a lot of overhead involved with tree sort) (if it wouldn't be, in general, they'd probably just replace that algorithm with tree sort).

---

I'm of course assuming there's nothing special about the data, which could make #1 faster.

[There are non-comparison-based sorting algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms), which perform better on different types of data with certain characteristics (typically numeric data).

If the data is already largely sorted, [insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) will actually run in `O(n)`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.. I think I'll rather use the 1st approach then.